# Lock Whole page while processing code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running some code to add products to a shopping cart. As I'm are simulating the product increment I'll have to give the page about 1000ms to acctually process the request to increment and add the product to the cart.

There are times when the customized form ends up in 10 or more products.

I have tried to hide everything beneath a gray div that has a high opacity, I cant use blockui since I'm running jquery 1.3 and that's in the framework I have to build upon.

This is what I do. **Why is it not working? I can't see the div at all?**

```
startLoad();
pdel = 1000;
$("input:submit[value='handla']").each(function(index)

   if(index != 1)
   {

      $("#backgroundPopup").text("Lägger produkt" + index + " i varukorgen");
      var submithing = this;  
      setTimeout(function(){ clicksubmitbutton(submithing); },pdel);
       pdel += 1000;
   }                      
});  

stopLoad();

 function startLoad(){
 $("#backgroundPopup").css("opacity", "0.7"); // css opacity, supports IE7, IE8

 $("#backgroundPopup").show();
 }
 function stopLoad()
 {
  $("#backgroundPopup").hide();
 }
```

CSS

```
#backgroundPopup {
z-index:1;
position: fixed;
display:none;
height:100%;
width:100%;
background:#000000;
top:0px;
left:0px;
}
```

Comment: You do of course have an element with that ID in the HTML ?

Comment: Yes I have :) sorry forgot to mention that part ...

Comment: Without the HTML posted I would say make sure your `backgroundPopup` is inside the `Body` tag or 100% width and height are only going to be of what ever the element is `backgroundPopup` is inside of.

Comment: @francois wahl ahh that migth be it :)

Answer (score 0):

Put your `stopLoad` function in DOM onReady. With jQuery you can do so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    stopLoad();
});
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's not related to your question. I thought you need lock page before loading.